# How to Add android menu overflow icon in my app

Tags: android, xml, button, menu, overflow

How to add Action overflow button manually on Layout.xml and when user click the button it should do some other task other than opening menu button.

[image: Menu Overflow]

Comment: Don't understand your question, you want a menu button to do what? Why can't you just add more menu items?

Comment: When user click on the menu button, a popup window with two items should appear on the top. But my actual question is how to add that three dots menu overflow button into my app i.e Layout.XMl and give button functionality. is there any inbuilt command to add menu overflow or i have to add image of menu overflow ???

Comment: http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/custom-options-menu-button-example

Answer (score 2):

The overflow icon only appears if the device doesn't have a hardware menu button and when you have an item in your menu.xml that looks like this,

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

android:showAsAction="never" will always add the item to the options menu or the overflow (depending on the device). It is a builtin in android given the condition stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method inside onCreate():

```
   private void getOverflowMenu() {

        try {
           ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
           Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
           if(menuKeyField != null) {
               menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
               menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
           }
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
```